# Is there any way to restore a deleted Google Webmasters property?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search

We have a situation that, when our client created a new "https" property under Google webmaster, he accidentally deleted the existing "http" property which had a good ranking. Since then (looks like) google started  pulling down the website from the listing in the search results for the same keyword we used for "http" site.

So my questions are:

1. **Is there any way to restore the deleted account from Google Webmasters ? Can google support help us?**
2. **Will google start removing (or pushing down) the site in search results, if the property is deleted in web masters.**

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that deleting the account would cause you to be deindexed

Comment: @jrtapsell you could use disallow * rule in your robots.txt to do that. If you want URLs removed asap, then you can submit them to be temporarily removed by Google from their index. However, apart from that (and on the positive side) submitting a sitemap for Googel to index URLs, Search console only allows you to manage your existing presence and view data pertaining to it. Simply creating or deleting a Search console account has no affect on our site's presence in Google's SERPs.

Comment: That is what I would have expected, I didn't want to say it for sure, as I was unaware if there were edge cases which would cause deletion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding or removing a property from Search Console has no effect on ranking, besides some minor edge cases (e.g. if you had set custom crawl settings or URL parameters). So any ranking drop you've seen is almost certainly a coincidence.

For the majority of data you see in GSC, Google collects that data whether or not there is an associated webmaster account. So when you delete a property, the only thing you may lose is some custom settings as mentioned above.

So yes, the http version can be restored simply by adding it back in Search Console. You can also 'group' separate properties (http/https and www/no-www) and see combined data for all properties.